# how to make sql in Active relation which has subquery in from clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have to make a SQL query using Active Relation.

> select  * from  (select * from `purchase_order_items` order by
>   `created_at` desc) as abc  where (fsn = '9788183071000' and sku
>   ='SKU0000000000000') or (fsn = 'BAGD7SHVZZPPVAZH' and sku ='SKU0000000000000')  or (fsn = 'CAMCUTS25Z2HSFE8' and sku ='SKU0000000000000') group by  fsn ,sku

What is the best and optimized way to do . I have tried

> PurchaseOrderItem.where("(fsn = '9788183071000' and sku
>   ='SKU0000000000000') or (fsn = 'BAGD7SHVZZPPVAZH' and sku ='SKU0000000000000')  or (fsn = 'CAMCUTS25Z2HSFE8' and sku ='SKU0000000000000')").order('created_at')

but then group is not happening as required .Table is decided by model name in rails. 
Is there any way to make above query ??

I don't want to pass it as plain query .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arel in order to make composed SQL queries.

```
p = PurchaseOrderItem.arel_table
User.where((p[:fsn].eq('9788183071000').and(p[:sku].eq('SKU0000000000000')).or(p[: fsn].eq('BAGD7SHVZZPPVAZH').and(p[:sku].eq('SKU0000000000000')).or(p[: fsn].eq('CAMCUTS25Z2HSFE8').and(p[:sku].eq('SKU0000000000000'))).order("fsn, sku")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is just me but I think the following sql query would return the same result than your query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM purchase_order_items
  WHERE (fsn = '9788183071000'    AND sku ='SKU0000000000000') 
     OR (fsn = 'BAGD7SHVZZPPVAZH' AND sku ='SKU0000000000000') 
     OR (fsn = 'CAMCUTS25Z2HSFE8' AND sku ='SKU0000000000000')
  GROUP BY fsn ,sku
  ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

If that is true, than you can write it in Rails like this:

```
combinations = [['9788183071000', 'SKU0000000000000'], ['BAGD7SHVZZPPVAZH', 'SKU0000000000000'], ['CAMCUTS25Z2HSFE8', 'SKU0000000000000']]

PurchaseOrderItem.where(
  Array.new(combinations.size, '(fsn = ? and sku = ?)').join(' OR '),
  combinations.flatten
).group('fsn, sku').order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: @T.J. How does it differ? Can you please provide more details: An example how your data and tables looks like and what you expect the query to return. From my point of view the only difference between your query and mine is the missing `order` clause. `group` does not guarantee to keep a given order. Therefore IMO that part is useless (or leads to unpredictable results). If you want a certain order, you should order you should order it in the second step. I updated my answer, please check again.